# The Typescript compiler throws an error even though the type definitions are exactly the same

Tags: reactjs, typescript, state

I get the following error:

```
Argument of type 'Element' is not assignable to parameter of type 'SetStateAction<Element[]>'.ts(2345)
```

The error happens in this line:

```
setCurrElements(allElements[shownIndex + 1])
```

This happens even though both elements are declared the same exact way:

```
const [allElements, setAllElements] = useState<JSX.Element[]>([])
const [currElements, setCurrElements] = useState<JSX.Element[]>([])
```

Many thanks for your help!

Comment: If you would have done `setCurrElements(allElements)` it would have worked since indeed the types are the same. But if you're accessing `allElements[shownIndex + 1]`, you have only a single `Element`!

Comment: Thank you! I actually declare allElements as a two dimensional array of elements. So TS THINKS it's just one elements when it fact it is an array that's passed. So I changed the declaration of currElements to:
    const [currElements, setCurrElements] = useState<JSX.Element[] | JSX.Element>([])

Comment: "*I actually declare `allElements` as a two dimensional array of elements*" - no you don't. At least not in the code you've shown.

Comment: Just for completeness sake, this is how the two dimensional array comes to be:
let preppedArray: any[] = []
      for (let i = 0; i < children.length; i++) {
        if (i % newVisAmount === 0) {
          preppedArray.push(children.slice(i, i + newVisAmount))
        }
      }
      setAllElements(preppedArray)

Comment: Uh, don't use `any`? Declare the type of `preppedArray` properly